# Несколько очередей анимации jQuery. Как остановить конкретные анимации?

Tags: jquery, анимация, очередь

Допустим у нас есть элемент, для которого заданы анимации по событию hover и по событию click.

По ховеру мы изменяем прозрачность элемента, по клику сворачиваем и сворачиваем (fadeToggle).

Чтобы избежать выполняющихся несколько раз изменений прозрачности, мы используем stop() при каждом ховере.

Когда мы кликнем по элементу, он начнет скрываться и сработает ховер (мышка уйдет с элемента, так или иначе) и сработает stop(). То есть остановится анимация сворачивающая элемент.

Как избежать этой ситуации? Я пробовал разнести анимации в 2 очереди и останавливать только одну из них. Но что-то у меня не получилось, видимо разные очереди выполняются последовательно.

Вот простой пример реализации
http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/0tj1yo8p

Comment: Код можете приложить?

Comment: Мм, ну тот код, где я работаю слишком большой. Это всего лишь маленькая часть функционала. Сейчас может сделаю чисто пример, с такой проблемой. Чуть позже выложу.

Comment: Приложил ;-) Нажмите на див и слегка поводите мышкой. Анимация остановится.

Answer (score 3):

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/onewug/1/). Такого поведения вы хотели добиться?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  test = $('div.test');

  test.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).dequeue();
    $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 300);
  });

  test.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).dequeue();
    $(this).animate({'opacity':0.3}, 300);
  });

  test.on('click', function() {
    $(this).queue(function(){
      $(this).slideToggle(1000);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Не совсем, но спасибо за пример, интересный для понимания.
Поведения хотел добиться, как снизу, только чтоб мышь вообще не влияла. Видимо нужно добавить еще $(this).off('mouseenter');

Comment: В примере у @Deonis slideToggle останавливается, если после начала сворачивания мышка успевает уйти и обратно зайти в область div.

Comment: А нет, получается что там событие мыши отключается вообще. Мне нужно чтобы эти события были как бы независимы. То есть смена прозрачности никак не влияла на анимацию сворачивания разворачивания.

Answer (score 3):

[Смотрим тут](http://cssdeck.com/labs/and0ayhv)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    test = $('div.test');

    test.on('mouseenter',function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':1}, 300);
    });
    test.on('mouseleave',function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':0.3}, 300);
    });

    test.on('click', function() {
        $(this).off('mouseleave');
        $(this).slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Так, но получается что если еще раз развернуть div то уже он не будет менять прозрачность при наведении?

Comment: @Blackmore, такие задачи строятся, исходя их определенной структуры и соответствующей логики. В вашем примере, если вы свернули блок, то естественно, что на него навести курсор уже не получиться. Значит для обратного действия, есть другой элемент, который за это отвечает и  снова повесить обработчик при разворачивании не составит труда.

Comment: Согласен, нужно было доделать пример. Но суть я уловил, спасибо ;-)
Сейчас попробую еще одним методом, если получится, сообщу.

Comment: Вот, может быть [этот пример](http://cssdeck.com/labs/obn2stqw) будет "ближе к телу"

Comment: Да, именно то, что нужно ;-)